# why my code is not supported in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

```
var searchKey = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    searchKey += Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xF).toString(0xF) + (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10 ? "|" : "");
}
searchKey = searchKey + "_";
document.getElementById('searchKey1').value = searchKey;
```

My code is working fine in IE8, but IE7 is not supported it shows
" 'document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object " 
why? please give the solution

Comment: Note that `0xF` is `15`, not `16`

Comment: it would be helpful if the question stated exactly what is going wrong. What is happening in IE7? What is supposed to be happening? What have you tried already to fix it?

Comment: And also, does it work in other browsers? It's fine to say that it doesn't work in IE7, but if it doesn't work in any browser, the problem isn't with IE7.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently IE7 breaks getElementById: [IE7 breaks getElementById](http://remysharp.com/2007/02/10/ie-7-breaks-getelementbyid/)

From that link:

> IE is treating the name attribute on forms as the ID attribute,

Comment: This is, based on the question, unlikely to be helpful IMO, but not impossible. It would be strange if one element has an ID `searchKey1` and a different element has a name `searchKey1`, and that's the one situation in which `getElementById` doesn't work right (according to your link).

Comment: +1 for answering a question without a question

Comment: @hvd that's right, but we never know...  ;)